# How to calculate the required bandwidth from a spectrum diagram? [FM]

Tags: frequency-spectrum, bandwidth

For example from this diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many definitions of bandwidth; see for example section 2.2 in [this book](http://sethares.engr.wisc.edu/telebreak.html) (PDF linked at the end of the page). In your case, it is easy to use the "absolute bandwidth", which is defined as $B=f_{max}-f_{min}$, where $f_{max}$ is the largest frequency in the spectrum, and $f_{min}$ is the smallest.

According to this definition, you'd have $B=(100.028-99.972)\mathrm{\,MHz}=56\mathrm{\,kHz}$.